# Possible to set up a management interface on a Cisco 2901?

Tags: cisco, router

I want to send a 2901 pre-configured to a remote site. The issue is that there might be some settings I need to change once it gets there. I would like to make a un-used gig interface a management interface so I can attache it to the network and access it.

It doesn't look like I can do that, does any one know of a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that dedicated management ports are usually configured in Cisco equipment (routers and switches, at least) is generally placing said port into its own vrf and then applying ACL's and such as appropriate to limit access.  The vrf serves as a completely separate routing table - which speaks to both requirement for potentially overlapping IP's as well as assuring that traffic cannot be forwarded through the isolated port.  You can also associate various services (snmp, aaa, etc) with the vrf to follow its particular routing requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain your requirements more?

The console port is the defacto management port.  Is there someone onsite that can access the console port and make config changes?  Will you be onsite with the box?

If not, what type of changes are you expecting to have to make?  If you're not confident that basic functionality will be there when it's plugged in, then you probably don't want to rely on a LAN interface for management access.  That said, yes you could telnet/ssh to the box, via a LAN port.  You need to configure the vty section of the config for this type of access.  Ensure it works before you ship it.  Also, take into account whatever conditions you expect to encounter onsite - VLAN trunks being plugged in, connections that haven't been setup for routing back to your workstation in some other path, etc.

Comment: No, the console port is the console port. A management port can be used for out of band (or in band device management). In this case I want to set up the un-used gig interface to be a non routed port that I can access once it is set up on the network. The router is replacing the router on site so if it is just plugged into the network there will be a IP conflict. I know management cards can be added but this is just a safety step I would like to take. Alternatively I will just connect the console cable to a server near by and connect to the server first.